# Express.io "Cannot read property of 'expires' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, centos

This is my first time working with node.js and I am trying to use express.io to save cookies.

I have literally carbon copied the tutorial ( https://github.com/techpines/express.io/tree/master/examples#sessions ) but I only receive this error:

```
root@server1 [/nodeexample]# node server.js

//Result after First Page Load
{ touch: [Function],
  resetMaxAge: [Function],
  save: [Function],
  reload: [Function],
  destroy: [Function],
  regenerate: [Function],
  name: 'test',
  feelings: 'test' }

//Result after refresh
 /nodeexample/node_modules/express.io/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session/memory.js:46
      expires = 'string' == typeof sess.cookie.expires
                                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'expires' of undefined
    at /nodeexample/node_modules/express.io/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session/memory.js:46:47
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

**Edit:** I have the main server file in **/nodeexample** and the client script in: **/home/mysite/public_html/nodetest**

I did notice the **app.get** does not seem to be getting called. the final alert comes back as **Also, you joined *undefined***

The error does not appear until the second refresh, and it seems as if it does work originally.

The Code I have is:

**Server:**

```
express = require('express.io')
app = express().http().io()

// Setup your sessions, just like normal.
app.use(express.cookieParser())
app.use(express.session({secret: 'monkey'}))


// Session is automatically setup on initial request.
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    req.session.loginDate = new Date().toString()
    res.sendfile('/home/mysite/public_html/nodetest/client.html')
})


// Setup a route for the ready event, and add session data.
app.io.route('ready', function(req) {
    req.session.name = req.data
    req.session.save(function() {
        req.io.emit('get-feelings')
    })
})

// Send back the session data.
app.io.route('send-feelings', function(req) {
    req.session.feelings = req.data
    req.session.save(function() {
        req.io.emit('session', req.session)
    })
    console.log(req.session);
})

app.listen(7076)
```

**Client:**

```
   <script src="http://localhost:7076/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:7076');

  // Emit ready event.
  socket.emit('ready', prompt('What is your name?'))

  // Listen for get-feelings event.
  socket.on('get-feelings', function () {
      socket.emit('send-feelings', prompt('How do you feel?'));
  })

  // Listen for session event.
  socket.on('session', function(data) {
      message = 'Hey ' + data.name + '!\n\n' 
      message += 'Server says you feel '+ data.feelings + '\n'
      message += 'I know these things because sessions work!\n\n'
      message += 'Also, you joined ' + data.loginDate + '\n'
      alert(message)
  })

</script>
```

I am not sure if I am missing a dependency or not? I loaded it with **npm install express.io**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why is the `app.get` part of the server commented out? what page is the client loading if there is no route?

Comment: I updated my question, I had tried this with the app.get commented out and having it added. I had *assumed* the node server should not be in the public_html folder since people would be able to access the scripts. I am still brand new to node.js and am trying to learn how it is all suppose to work. I assume its something very straightforward I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I figured it out finally, Ben led me on the right direction and it was due to the **app.get** function. It was a miss understanding of where the client file was suppose to be.

The **req.sendfile** will actually send the html to the port when it is opened. I had the client file in public_html of my website where instead it should have been in the node server folder.

This way when you go to www.whateveryoursiteis.com:7076 it would load it load the html client for you.

```
Files:
/node/server.js
/node/client.html

Run: node /node/server.js

Load: www.yoursite.com:7076
```

*I figured this was a pretty simple mistake, this answer might help another newbie on his way*